# some node_modules work, some don't

Tags: npm, react-native

In my index.ios.js I put:

```
var moment = require('moment')
```

near the top and it works fine but

```
var formatTime = require('minutes-seconds-milliseconds')
```

right below it will not. both packages were installed the same way with

```
npm install --save <moment/minutes-seconds-milliseconds>
```

here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "stopwatch",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "minutes-seconds-milliseconds": "^1.0.3",
    "moment": "^2.14.1",
    "react": "15.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.29.0"
  }
}
```

npm -V returns `npm@3.10.3 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm`
I'm using OS X 10.11.5

could this be at all related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968?

I've tried deleting node_modules and npm install'ing again but that hasn't worked. I've also tried react-native init'ing a new project and that also hasn't worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please do once like this:

```
import {moment} from 'moment';
import {formatTime} from 'minutes-seconds-milliseconds';
```

Comment: why did this work and not the standard require format?

Comment: this might be the problem in library that you have imported, the library you imported is written in new ECMA script and your code is in old script. For details you can see here: http://reactjs.net/guides/es6.html

Comment: also, when adding a node_module it took me a while to remember that you have to quit the current node program and run npm start